# How to change the name of grub boot loader folder /boot to something else?

Tags: linux, grub, boot-loader

Title kind of says it all.  I'm really trying to understand if the location of /boot is hardcoded into grub or what?

If bios looks at first 512 and finds grub...then grub must have it hard coded to look into /boot?

Am I accurate on that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard coded into grub. If you take a look at a boot entry from a GRUB configuration file, like this:

```
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.4.21-1.ent)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.21-1 ro root=/dev/sda2
        initrd /initrd-2.4.21-1.img
```

you'll see the line `root (hd0,0)`. This is the definition of the boot partition, hard disk 0, partition 0 in this case (which is usually addressed within Linux as `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/hda1`, or something similar, depending on the hardware).

When you run `grub-install` this configuration is read and stored into the boot loader area along with the grub binary. But you can just edit these entries while you are on the GRUB screen to boot from a different partition.

To mount this partition on the `/boot` path is a Linux/Unix convention, see the [Filesystem Hierachy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). You could mount it anywhere you want, but you would need to adapt packages and tools related to the kernel and the boot loaded to make them aware of the new location.

Comment: It was quite unexpected to see a grub v1 configuration as an example in 2023 ;)

Answer (score 0):

The location of `/boot` is not so much hard coded, as *embedded* into GRUB's code at the time GRUB is installed.

Since you mentioned "first 512", I assume you are thinking about the `i386-pc` architecture variant of GRUB, i.e. the variant for classic BIOS-style boot.

When GRUB is installed in the Master Boot Record, the code within the actual MBR is only enough to load one more block (because of all the legacy compatibility options the boot code needs to have with a regular BIOS). The block number of the next block is embedded into GRUB's MBR code as part of the process of installing GRUB to the MBR.

If you are using classic MBR partitioning, the next block will normally be the block just after MBR (block #1). It will contain some more GRUB code and a list of more blocks to read. These blocks will contain:

- the remaining blocks of the GRUB core image
- the minimum necessary set of GRUB modules to allow GRUB understand and access the partition table and the filesystem that contains rest of the GRUB modules (i.e. normally, the filesystem that contains the `/boot/grub` directory)
- a GRUB prefix, which indicates which partition and directory within it GRUB should look for its configuration file and for more GRUB modules as necessary.

On a MBR-partitioned disk, these blocks will be embedded in the normally-unused space between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition. The blocklist is also produced by the `grub-install` process at GRUB installation time.

If the `i386-pc` GRUB is installed on a GPT-partitioned disk, the space between block #0 and the beginning of the first partition is occupied by the GPT partition table structures, so a dedicated "biosboot" partition will be used for these parts of GRUB instead.

If you wanted to change the name of the `/boot` directory to something else, you would just have to specify it with a `--boot-directory=` option to `grub-install`, and it would automatically adjust the prefix information that gets embedded into the raw disk blocks used by the initial phases of GRUB.

---

Just for the sake of completeness: on UEFI systems with Secure Boot, the entire GRUB core image and **all** the GRUB modules required by the boot process are written into a single file on the EFI System Partition (ESP), usually named `grubx64.efi`. This would be the `x86_64-efi` variant of GRUB.

In order to UEFI Secure Boot firmware to accept this file, it needs to be a Microsoft PE+-formatted binary that has a valid signature, either by one of the Secure Boot keys accepted by the system firmware, by the provider of the Secure Boot compatibility shim (`shimx64.efi`), or by the Machine Owner's Key (MOK) optionally installed by the system administrator.

An increasing number of distributions seem to be placing a mini-configuration file for UEFI GRUB to the ESP, named `grub.cfg`, in the same directory as `grubx64.efi`. This file will usually contain only a few configuration lines: just enough to identify the filesystem, directory and filename that contains the actual GRUB configuration. So on UEFI systems, on many distributions, if you wanted to change the name of `/boot` to something else, you could do it without reinstalling GRUB by just editing the `/boot/efi/EFI/<distro_name>/grub.cfg` file.